# C++/WinRT Console app for IoT Core stuck on splash screen

Tags: c++, windows-10-iot-core

This is just out-the-box (as directed [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp)) from the template and pushed to the (virtualbox) emulated device by doing a Remote Machine debug session.

Why is it stuck on the splash-screen? Anybody come across the same? Have I missed something?

When I run it it deploys fine giving this debug output (nothing to speak of, I don't think):

```
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\cc60f819-ef47-4858-b213-8af8c3669919VS.Debug_Win32.nm1\ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32legacy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug_14.0.26428.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\vcruntime140d_app.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppxLayouts\cc60f819-ef47-4858-b213-8af8c3669919VS.Debug_Win32.nm1\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleCppWinRt3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\procthreadexthost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0xd38 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**Edit**
If I pause the debugger it's in console code. But the splash screen is still in the way or something. e.g. In this code the debugger is in the `getchar()` call:

```
int main()
{
    wprintf(L"Hello IoT");
    getchar();
}
```

But in this code:

```
int main()
{
    wprintf(L"Hello IoT");
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

...it's in the `Sleep` call, but after the 10sec it closes causing Visual Studio to declare:

> Unable to activate windows store app [...]. The myapp.exe process
>   started but activation request failed with error 'The app didn't
>   start'.

I'm not supposed to call something to close the splash screen or something obvious, am I?

Comment: Hi noelicus, I create a C++/WinRT Console app and debug on Windows IoT Core device(Raspberry Pi) but failed to start. Did you debug on Windows 10 IoT Core/Enterprise VM set up in the VirtualBox?

Comment: I haven't tried debugging it ... there's hardly any code there, but will try that now.

Comment: Ok. Seems I have misunderstood. Can you clarify this "emulated device by doing a Remote Machine debug session"? My understanding is deploying works but debugging not.

Comment: It deploys and runs the app with debugger attached and the machine just displays the app's splash screen.